# Combine java to c

Tags: java, c, user-interface

I am new to programing.
 "Now I have **written a c program(simple calculator) and i want to make a GUI using java and combine those together**". 
How can I do that ?  It would be a great help if any one can provide simple example code. Actually I'm quite lost now. Please help. Tank you

Comment: unless you do this to learn c-java interaction this is a bad idea. rewrite your c code in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your C code into a shared library then you can call the native C code from Java, this article shows you how.

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.09/CallingCCodefromJava/index.html

Answer (score 5):

First, if it isn't really necessary, I would avoid doing that.

If you want to call native code from Java program, you should use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). This will require preparation in the C side of your code, but it works pretty good. If you are new to programming, again, I would recommend avoiding that.

Regarding GUI - you can work with [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Agree. Java works best with all code being in Java.  You _CAN_ call native code from within Java, but it is relatively cumbersome and hard to debug.  Leave it to later.

Comment: Finally I found what I was looking for... I did it with GTK+ <a>www.gtk.org</a>

Comment: I don't know why the idiotic people Mitch Wheat, cularis, Bart Kiers, Kerrek SB, herbalessence tried to close this question...

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading about [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would stick to C/C++ giving the fact that the backend of the calculator is already written in C. Going to Java for the GUI will just make things a little bit harder unnecessarly, unless ofcourse you absolutely want to tinker with these kind of things for the purpose of learning something new. There are windowing/GUI libraries out there for C++ that you could use which are also cross platform(if that might be one of the resons going for Java):

- [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) - I think it's pretty easy to learn and use and it has good documentation and [tutorials](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials.htm)
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) - one more coming with a lot of documentation and community support
- [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) - if you would like to "mess" a bit with OpenGL stuff; it does not look to fancy but it can do the job
- [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) - for OpenGL fancyness; the process of using this one might be more involved as you might have to build it from sources

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366043/what-are-some-of-the-best-cross-platform-c-ui-toolkits-today) could provide also some additional insights.
Have fun :)